# Simple attribute data rules in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, data-validation

I would like to add some simple attribute validation in my current workflow. This is with regards to a point shapefile:

1. Required fields
2. Fields that become required if one optional field is populated
3. An 'ok' field that notifies the user that all required fields have
   been populated

How would this be done?

Comment: That kind of flow is (realistically) just not possible with shapefiles, the format is old and doesn't have anything fancy - which is one of the reasons why it's so widely adopted. Geodatabase feature classes can have subtypes and domain-controlled fields which will give you some sort of logic but to validate on store you'll really need something else, an addin or trigger on an enterprise database. Do you have any ArcObjects ability? How much work are you prepared to put into this?

Comment: I'm the same user to whom you so generously donated the Add-In you developed yesterday. I am beginning to sense this ArcObjects thing is quite essential to learn...

Comment: How's that going for you? Were you able to download it and use it? I'm new to Google Drive so I don't know if I did it correctly... You can have subtypes and domains quite easily, which controls what you can and can't put into fields but to validate on store/save is really quite something different. I can point you in the right direction but I don't have (much) code around that. ArcObjects will take a long time to learn but as you've asked two questions in two days that it would provide a solution for I would think in your situation it might be worth investigating.

Comment: I have set it aside for the moment as I have a large database to manually input. I am aiming to use it in the near future as my main reference to begin learning about ArcObjects and how to use them. It looks like a longer term effort that I need to really focus on. So thanks for the educational and practical value you've provided.

Comment: Perhaps read up on subtypes http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_subtypes/005r00000003000000/ , default values http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001s00000009000000 and coded value domains http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_new_coded_value_domain/001s00000004000000/ and leave the validation to a python script that can be run intermittently. However domains and subtypes can only be created on SDE, file or personal geodatabase feature classes so you're going to need to import it to use those.

Comment: What precisely is your "current workflow" into which you wish to inject "Required fields"?  Please use the **edit** button to provide more details.  Once we have worked through "Required fields" we can look at your second and third "types" of fields, possibly as separate questions.  Also, what version are you using?  If it is earlier than 10.1 then that could make a difference to whether solutions are possible.